# Understanding React Function Component Syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner learning ReactJS from react docs. The docs gave an example that I am having trouble understanding and implementing. Will you please help me find my mistake?[image: my img]
This is my code:

```
import React from 'react'

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      function formatName(user) {
      return user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;
}

      const user = {
      firstName: 'Harper',
      lastName: 'Perez'
};

      const element = (
      <h1>
        Hello, {formatName(user)}!
      </h1>
      );
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: You shouldn't define functions within your return method. Typically, you'll define functions before the return method. Define `formatName` and `user` before the `return` code and just reference it from the JSX.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should double check with your example, and maybe switch to a different tutorial. The code given doesn't really work with react in any way that makes sense.

Comment: @can i get a example pls?

Comment: @Robert P from where can i learn now? am learning from reactjs official website

Comment: This code is not in the React docs; you've cut-and-pasted code in the React docs into a seemingly arbitrary location in other different code. There's a [tutorial on the React site](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) (although it's not overly-current) and there are *tons* of modern React tutorials all over the web.

Comment: Questions on SO should at minimum have a title that briefly describes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining functions and variables within your `return` JSX code that is later rendered. Typically, you define such functions and variables inside the function component but before the return statement. Try this modification of your code to see if it resolves your issue.

```js
import React from 'react'

function App() {
    function formatName(user) {
        return user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;
    }

    const user = {
        firstName: 'Harper',
        lastName: 'Perez'
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>
        Hello, {formatName(user)}
        </h1>
      </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```